# Move a Shape from Windows Phone 8 on Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

im developing some windows phone 8 apps 
and i got the next doubt:

I have 8x8 Grid, like a game table, and rectangles on all of the cells 
of my grid, at avery cell, there is a Rectangle shape where is assumed to 
contain a card game, so, here is the deal, I need to move the card shape by ManipulationDeltaEventArgs, but I cannot rearrange that shape to the next grid cell

I thought it would be something like *myShape.Grid.Row++;* but there is not the parent grid on my 
shape attributes 
would you please help me ?

my XAML file looks like this

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>

    <!--I want to move this ellipse to the next row and collumn by drag and drop
    and I already have that code, I just want to move it and stretch it to the 
    rectangle it is dropped
    <Ellipse x:Name="e10" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="45" Heigth="45" ManipulationCompleted="e10_ManipulationCompleted_1"/>
</Grid>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Row property the following way:

```
myShape.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, (int)myShape.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty) + 1 );
```

or:

```
Grid.SetRow(myShape, Grid.GetRow(myShape) + 1);
```